# Delimited text layer not showing up on map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, error

[image: CRS transformation prompt][image: delimited text file]I am using QGIS 3.14.15 on MacOS. I have added a delimited text layer (csv file converted from xlsx) as a new shapefile. It shows up on the "Layers" section at the bottom left but not on the map. If I click "Zoom to layer," it shows up but everything else disappears. When I undo it, the layer disappears again. Made sure coordinates were represented on X and Y axis. Any ideas?

[image][adding delimited text layer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEOlM.png) 
[[image: showing import of csv (part 1)][image: ][3]]

[image: when I click "Zoom to layer" it shows up, but everything else disappears]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.Stackexchange Euan! Please add some screenshots of the add layer dialog, the loaded layer, and the attribute table so we can narrow things down

Comment: Hi and thanks, @underdark ! I just added some images. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: Yes, that helps! As bugmenot123 mentioned, the problem is with the CRS configuration of the biovailable layer. If you want / can share (a sample) of that layer, we can have a look at what the CRS should be.

Answer (score 2):

Your other layer has a wrong georeference. Your map is set to EPSG:4326 but your coordinate display shows coordinates that are rather UTM or something similar.

Fix that and your data will align.

You can test the validity by adding a rough outline of continents if you enter the text "world" in the coordinate display and hit the Enter key.

Comment: Hmm.. I went back and made sure to set the rest of the layers to EPSG:4326 and the new layer to the same coordinates system but it still didn't work

Comment: Do not randomly *override* them to EPSG:4326, their CRS setting in QGIS must be the one their coordinates are actually in. Try reloading all layers in a fresh new project and before overriding anything, question if that is really what you need.

Comment: I see, thanks. It looks like the original Greenland shapefile has no coordinate reference system set at all. Is that maybe the issue?

Comment: Definitely so :) If you do not know its CRS try loading it, find a point you could identify on a OSM map and enter the coordinates of that point in http://projfinder.com/ and see if it gives you something reasonable (switch X and Y if unsure ;) ).

Comment: Ok, thanks! I plugged in one of the GPS points into projfinder and got "EPSG:4284 Name:Pulkovo 1942" as the closest point (rank 0). I started a new project, I set my project CRS to EPSG:4284, loaded the original shapefile as a new layer, and set it to the same project CRS. Made sure the layer is at the top, double checked the symbology, but it's still not showing up on the map.

Comment: EPSG:4284 would be a very surprising CRS for data that is in Greenland. Are you sure you did not mix up your X and Y? https://epsg.io/4284-5044

Comment: I think you may be right. I went back and double-checked. Looks like EPSG:4267 - NAD27 is the closest, which makes more sense. I tried the same thing with the new CRS but it still doesn't work. Started a new project like usual, changed project CRS, then uploaded the shapefile. When I first upload the shapefile, I get a prompt about "multiple actions needed" to change the CRS and I've always just clicked "Ok." Am I missing a step, maybe? (I'll add an image to the post to help show you what I mean)

Comment: Well, don't blindly click OK but read that it says and if you are unsure what it means, add screenshots of the prompts to your question here.

Comment: My colleague was able to fix it by going back to the original excel file by converting the Lat Long (originally listed DSM) to decimal coordinates, converting it into a new .cvs, then uploading it in ARCGIS as a WGS 1984 and converting it to the coordinate system used on the original shp. The original shp has a custom coordinate system that might not be compatible with QGIS. Thanks so much for your help bugmenot123! You helped me explore the software which I already like a lot